# Change Select tag value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, select, getelementbyid

I'm trying to change a value from a select tag using JavaScript. Let's say that I have this textbox, and if that textbox is null, no changes will be done and the value of the select tag options will be as is. But if that textbox is filled, then I have to assign a different value aside from the ones in the select tag options.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtTest" />
<select name="rdoSelect" id="rdoSelect">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
if (document.getElementById('txtTest').value===null)
{
    document.getElementById('rdoSelect').value;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('rdoSelect').value = "option 3";
}
```

I can't make it work. I've tried pointing it to an element/variable rather than to a value and it still doesn't work:

```
var test = document.getElementById('rdoSelect');
test.value = "option 3";
```

I need help, please. Thanks!

Comment: you have to change the `selected` attribute on the option element (and deselect all option before that)

Comment: A value of an text input will never be `null`. If there's no text in the input, it's value is `''`. This does nothing: `document.getElementById('rdoSelect').value;`. You can change the selected value of an `select` element by setting its `selectedIndex`. Though setting `value` of `select` element might work in some browsers, you can't rely it'll do the job in all browsers.

Comment: Why you compare with null instead of blank string? ` =="" `

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry. I thought you could compare it to null. My bad. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SelectIndex method. Please refer the below code.

I added OnChange event to input text to test this sample.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

    function test()
    {   
        if (document.getElementById('txtTest').value=='')
        {
            document.getElementById("rdoSelect").selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("rdoSelect").selectedIndex = 1;
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txtTest" onchange="test();" />
<select name="rdoSelect" id="rdoSelect">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually find this easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening on button click or onkeyup? Either way in the function you can add value to dropdownlist using this:

```
dropdownlist.append(
    $("<option selected='selected'></option>").val(sValId).html(sVal)
);
```

Or you colud try this

```
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = "--Select--";
optn.value = "0";
baseCurve.options.add(optn);`
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMLSelectElement doesn't let you set the `value` directly. It's possible to have many or zero `<option>`s with a particular value, so it's not a straightforward 1:1 mapping.

To select an option you can either set its `selected` property to `true`, or set the `selectedIndex` property of the select to the option number.

There is no `option 3` in your select—are you trying to add a new option?

eg

```
function setOrCreateSelectValue(select, value) {
    for (var i= select.options.length; i-->0;) {
        if (select.options[i].value==value) {
            select.selectedIndex= i;
            return;
        }
    }
    select.options[select.options.length]= new Option(value, value, true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (document.getElementById('txtTest').value===null)
    {
        document.getElementById('rdoSelect').value;
    }
    else
    {
       var val = document.getElementById('txtTest').value
       for(var i, j = 0; i = rdoSelect.options[j]; j++) {
        if(i.value == val) {
            rdoSelect.selectedIndex = j;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsfiddle, it's using jquery, which
is probably the most common solution. Hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/GkLsZ/

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnChange').on('click', function() {
        var value = $.trim($('#txtTest').val());

        if (!!value) {
            $('#rdoSelect')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", value)
                .attr("selected", "selected")
                .text(value)); 
        }
    });
});
```